# powershell redirect error from az cli command

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I'm running an az CLI command `az mysql db show`. At first, the DB doesn't exist, but that case is handled in a try/catch block. There is an error message printed:

> ERROR: The requested resource of type 'Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/databases' with name 'my_name' was not found.

I would like to not print this message since I'm handling the error case. I tried different methods to [redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1) the error output stream to null. I didn't manage to do so. I tried:

```
command 2> $null # not working
```

and other approaches.

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# from python in windows
az mysql db show 2>nul

# from powershell in windows - no space!
az mysql db show 2>$null
```

This should work better for you. <s>Powershell will eat your `$null`, so azure cli won't redirect.</s>

You can also try checking for the db first with `az mysql db list`

Comment: By using `2>nul` I get the following error
> Out-File: FileStream was asked to open a device that was not a file. For support for devices like 'com1:' or 'lpt1:', call CreateFile, then use the FileStream constructors that take an OS handle as an IntPtr.

Comment: @Vivere I misread the notes I was using - In Powershell, use `2>$null` (no spaces). See this old issue for details: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/10856

Comment: So after a while, I figured out what was wrong. Both `2> $null` and `2>$null` work, but sadly I was running them in `VSCode's PowerShell Integrated Console` while I was debugging a script. It doesn't work there apparently.